# Hatcher Question 1.2.10 - Show that the loop $\gamma$ is nullhomotopic

Tags: algebraic-topology, fundamental-groups

See page 53 of Hatcher's Algebraic topology for reference to image. Consider two arcs $\alpha$ and $\beta$ embedded in $D^2 \times I$ as shown in the figure. The loop $\gamma$ is obviously nullhomotopic in $D^2 \times I$, but show that there is no nullhomotopy of $\gamma$ in the complement of $\alpha \cup \beta$.

My reasoning is to consider the fundamental group of the space $(D^2 \times I) - (\alpha \cup \beta)$. To calculate the fundamental group of this space, we let $X = D^2 \times I, A = X - S^1$ and $B = X - S^1$ in such a way that $A \cap B = X - (\alpha \cup \beta)$. So by van Kampen's theorem, we have an isomorphism $$\frac{\pi_1(A) \ast \pi_1(B)}{N} \cong \pi_1(X).$$ This is given by $$\frac{\mathbb{Z} \ast \mathbb{Z}}{N} \cong 0$$ This obviously does not work and I'm not sure of how to proceed.

Comment: Whilst I know what you mean by $A=X-S^1$, note that you are dealing with arcs, not loops, and that you should specify the embedding (otherwise one may think $A=B$). As for your question, I suggest you try to choose $A$ and $B$ accordingly to compute the fundamental group of $X=(D^2\times I)-(\alpha \cup \beta)$ rather than just $X=D^2 \times I$, the latter of which is contractible anyway.

Answer (score 3):

I'll add the figure from Hatcher for clarity.

[image]

The key here is to note that the knot can be undone by moving one edge of each arc from one side of the cylinder across to the other side. I actually figured this out playing with two strings.

Now, you have a full cylinder minus two straight lines. This has a deformation retract to a disk with two holes, which is in turn homeomorphic to a wedge of $2$ circles - so it has the fundamental group $F_2=\langle a,b\rangle$.

Now, throughout this process you need to keep track of where $\gamma$ is. At this point, it encompasses both holes. So after the retract to a wedge of $2$ circles, $\gamma$ is represented by $a\circ b$. In $F_2$, one has $a\circ b\neq e$. So $\gamma$ is not null-homotopic.

[I would like to thank @ChesterX and @Juggler for pointing out an error in my answer, hence the edit.]

Comment: $\mathbb{D}^3$ minus two _non-intersecting_ lines deformation retracts onto a disc $\mathbb{D}^2$ minus two points, which is homotopy equivalent to wedge of $2$ circles.

Comment: Right idea but wrong answer. ChesterX is right. The fundamental group is a free group with two generators.

Comment: @ChesterX and Juggler, you are absolutely right. I corrected the answer accordingly.

Comment: I apologize for commenting on an old post, but I believe that $\gamma$ actually represents a commutator of generators in $F_2$. I will post an answer with illustrations to demonstrate.

Answer (score 2):

Here are the details of @Whyka's answer worked out. I believe $\gamma$ represents a commutator of generators in $F_2$. Here's the original layout given in the problem:

[image: Stage 1]

We shrink $\gamma$ as to move it off of the boundary of the cylinder. We can then move the bottom strand of $\beta$ across the front of the cylinder to the left, and the bottom strand of $\alpha$ across the back of the cylinder to the right:

[image: Stage 2]

We would now like to untangle $\alpha$ and $\beta$ by moving the left strand of $\alpha$ in front of the left strand of $\beta$. In order to do this, we first adjust $\gamma$ to make room:

[image: Stage 3]

Finally we can untangle $\alpha$ and $\beta$ by moving the left strands into the "crevices" created in $\gamma$ in the previous step:

[image: Stage 4]

After we deformation retract onto $S^1\vee S^1$, we see that $\gamma$ indeed represents a commutator of generators in $\pi_1(S^1\vee S^1)\cong F_2$.